# I get an error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reduce')

Tags: reactjs, pie-chart

```js
const total = slices.reduce((totalValue, value) => totalValue + value, 0);
//then i have mapped 

if (value === total) {
      return (
        <circle r={radius} cx={center} cy={center} fill={color} key={index} />
      );
    }

if (value === 0) {
  return;
}

const valuePercentage = value / total;

const longArc = valuePercentage <= 0.5 ? 0 : 1;

radSegment += valuePercentage * radCircumference;
const nextX = Math.cos(radSegment) * radius;
const nextY = Math.sin(radSegment) * radius;

//like this i retun to get the output
{renderPaths(this.props.slices)}
```

Hi, I'm new to this charts. while use the pie chart i'm thiserror, Please help me to solve this error.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The error's telling you that `slices` is undefined. What is that variable? Where's it come from? What's is supposed to be?

Answer (score 1):

Add ? after slices:

```
const total = slices?.reduce((totalValue, value) => totalValue + value, 0);
```